# How to add | remove css class in angular element?

Tags: css, angular

How to add | remove css class in angular element?

Access to angular element is via: `this.elementRef.nativeElement` (`import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core';`).
CSS class name is `myclass`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
constructor(public elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer)
{
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elementRef, 'class');
   // or 

            this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('class');

}
```

1. Using Renderer
2. Using addClass on Native element

Answer (score 3):

You can use HostBinding to do that, without using a Renderer or ElementRef. See this example :

```
import {Component, HostBinding} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
   ...
})
export class myComponent {
    @HostBinding('class.myclass') visible: boolean = false;  // True when visible
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of doing do one by using (ElementRef, Renderer) or by using Hostbinding
Below example demonstrate to add and remove the class based on a click event 
Hostbinding eg:
with help of variable, I am attaching an open(instead of open you can even add your class name) class to the HTML element.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropDown]",
})
export class DropdownDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.open') isOpen = false;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {

  }

  @HostListener('click') click(eventData: Event) {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen
  }
}
```

---

ElementRef eg:
Below example is for the Add method when you are using renderer

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2, } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
  selector: "[appDropDown]",
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {

  }

  @HostListener('click') click(eventData: Event) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'class', 'open');
  }
}
```

if you are not using renderer then for direct native element u can use 
    **this.elementRef.nativeElement.classList.add('class')**

Note:Renderer2 is for angula6 version though`